# Use ReactJs components in a tsx components in Astro

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I have an astro based framework and I wondering if the following is possible:
I have an .astro page with this code

```
<BaseLayout title={`My title`}>
  <main>
    <Navbar client:only />
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="my-5">
        <ProductPageDetail
          
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </main>
</BaseLayout>
```

I wonder if in `ProductPageDetail` (an astro component) I can use `reactjs` client side code.

I tried to add this in my component

```
<AddToCart client:only></AddToCart>
```

inside my `ProductPageDetail` but I have this error

```
Type '{ "client:only": true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

So my question is how to have a client rendered component inside a server side rendered component?
Is this even possible?
I put some `console.log("test")` inside my `AddToCart` but I see the message server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`client:only`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#clientonly) directive requires the component's framework as a value

```
<SomeReactComponent client:only="react" />
<SomePreactComponent client:only="preact" />
<SomeSvelteComponent client:only="svelte" />
<SomeVueComponent client:only="vue" />
<SomeSolidComponent client:only="solid-js" />
```

Comment: No, it does not work, the same error. I tried to put a console.log in AddToCart and I see the message server side.  I can use client:only but only in a .astro page. Here I'm trying in a tsx file (included in an .astro page)

Comment: `client:only` is only available inside `.astro`, you can try migrating your component to a `.astro` file or passing it as a slot from a `.astro` file

Comment: Interesting. What do you mean by passing it as a slot?

Comment: There is a page in the docs about passing slots to UI Frameworks here: [Passing Children to Framework Components](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#passing-children-to-framework-components)

Comment: Thanks, actually the simplest ideas was to move the code in an .astro file and then load the button client:only. I didn't think at that before. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This depend on what you needs

For React is needed to be a client only code

```js
<ReactComponent client:only="react"/>
//This will not run when you are developing, you have to build and then run the from build to see it
<ReactComponent client:visible/>
//This will only run when the user gets into its viewports which is better for performance, and first-time load
```

considering that all this should be wrapped inside a .astro component

you can see here all the client directives and their use case

https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#client-directives